# Web development; no server source control support

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, svn, version-control

I'm developing web app using CodeIgniter PHP framework. The server I'm working with does not support any type of source control (i.e. Subversion) unless you go to a higher price tier.

I would still like to put the code under some sort of source control. Does it make sense to do the following:

1. Install git or SVN on my local machine and develop there
2. Copy changes from my local machine to development directory on the server (using FileZilla, WinSCP, etc.) and test
3. Copy changes from development directory to production directory on the server

Does that sound reasonable? Are there better alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: sounds sensible to me, especially if you do your testing locally.

Comment: Although just having a simple 1-1 mirror of your local files to your remote server doesn't allow you to easily roll back to an earlier version of your web app if something goes wrong once you deploy. Tools made for web app deployment like Capistrano can help in that regard, see my answer below

Comment: You can use [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) to deploy from a Git repository to a host accessible only via FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using svn locally it's a bit dangerous because then you will need to protect also your computer - I think the best way is to work with the commercial sites offer fully supported svn/git - like http://www.beanstalkapp.com/ or http://www.github.com

Comment: What? What does using local version control on your computer have to do with security?

Comment: @Cryode - just in a way that your computer looses it's hardisk or something - not security in a sense someone will go inside your computer from distance - I don't think if you are working on a serious projects, keeping the original code only under your pc (even with svn) - is safe

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you meant in regards to protecting it from hackers or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could use source control on your local machine (SVN, Git, etc.) and use an open source tool like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to deploy the code from your local source control repo to your server via SSH. Or if you're limited to FTP, this [blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/m5kpuq) has a potential solution.

An advantage of using a tool like Capistrano instead of directly mirroring the files on your local machine to the server via FileZilla or WinSCP is that Capistrano will *version* your deployed files so that, if you end up breaking something and need to roll back quickly to the previously-deployed version, it can be as easy as changing a symlink to the previous deployment directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that sound reasonable?

Partially, in p.1. But even in this case I'll suggest to have your repository also at some Repository-Hosting (BitBucket, GitHub, Assembla)

For pp. 2-3: your deploys must to be automatic and non-interactive, thus - you'll have to select another tools (for using in post-commit hook of SCM-of-choice)

*Somehow better* alternative to 2-3 may be:

- Use 2 different branches (DEVEL and PROD) as sources of DEVEL and PROD dir
- Post-commit hook, which upload *only changed in committed revision* files to corresponding dir (NCFTP for FTP, SCP with scenario for ssh)
- Main development happens in DEVEL branch
- PROD have **only mergesets** from DEVEL

Workflow is SCM-agnostic and scalable to any reasonable amount of branches and developers